# Solving Base of Modular Exponential Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am fairly new to modular exponential arithmetic and I came across the discrete logarithm problem which, for equation
$$c = a^b mod(n)$$
 it is extremely hard to solve for b, when we know the values for c, a and n. My question is, does this same problem still apply if, instead of solving for b, we are solving for the base a? That is, given c, b and n, is there a easily computable way to solve for a, or is this still considered part of the discrete logarithm problem?
Thanks for any information